# Matlab: How to create a loop for reading an matrix based on specific column values

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix as follows:

```
merged = 

'A05'    'a001'
'A06'    'a001'
'B05'    'a001'
'B06'    'a001'
'C01'    'a001'
'C02'    'a001'
'C03'    'a001'
'C04'    'a001'
'C05'    'a001'
'C06'    'a001'
'D01'    'a001'
'D02'    'a001'
'D03'    'a001'
'D05'    'a001'
'D04'    'a001'
'D06'    'a001'
'A03'    'a002'
'A04'    'a002'
'B03'    'a002'
'B04'    'a002'
```

Is it possible to make a loop, which read `a001` rows first and then read `a002` in the second round?

Thanks,
Woody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that loop-solutions are in general slow in Matlab,
but if you want it, here is a variant

```
tags = {'a001','a002'};
for i=1:length(tags)
  M = merged(strcmp(merged(:,2),tags{i}));
end
```

then you can operate on M in each itteration

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to automatically put `a001` and `a002` into `tags` when I have more tags?

Comment: very simple and just what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Find the rows that contains 'a001'. Then select all columns for those rows

```
A = merged(find(merged(:,2)=='a001'),:)

A = merged(find(merged(:,2)=='a002'),:)
```

or you can sort them accordinf to the second column and then apply your for loop

```
sorted = sortrows(merged,2);
for i=1:1:size(sorted,1)
    % Do what you need
end
```

Info on [sortrows()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html)

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to make a loop that reads `a001` and `a002` in sequential?

Comment: Do you mean in a for loop? line by line?

Comment: Yes, in a `for loop`. I hope to read `a001` rows first and then `a002` rows.

Comment: More precisely, I want to make a hash or `container.Map` to store `a001` and `a002` as keys so that I can create a loop to read `a001` and `a002`, respectively.

Comment: Could you please put an example in the `% Do what you need`? For example, if I want to extract `A05`.

Comment: You said you wanted them in order. You wanted `a001` first, then `a002`. The loop does that. ` % Do what you need` is where you create your hash table or whatever you wanted to do. If you want to extract `A05` before `a001` then that is different to what you listed in your question.